# If $\theta=\cos^{-1}\sqrt{\cos x}-\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\cos x}$, then $\sin\theta=$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\theta=\cos^{-1}\sqrt{\cos x}-\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\cos x}$, then $\sin\theta=$

$$\theta=\cos^{-1}\sqrt{\cos x}-\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\cos x}$$
$$\theta=\cos^{-1}\sqrt{\cos x}-\cos^{-1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\cos x+1}}$$

Taking sin at both sides

$$\sin\theta=\sin\left(\cos^{-1}\sqrt{\cos x}-\cos^{-1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\cos x+1}}\right)$$
$$\sin\theta=\sin(\sin^{-1}{\sqrt{1-\cos x}})\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\cos x+1}}-\sin\left(\sin^{-1}\dfrac{\sqrt{\cos x}}{\sqrt{\cos x+1}}\right)\sqrt{\cos x}$$

$$\sin\theta=\dfrac{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}{\sqrt{1+\cos x}}-\dfrac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1+\cos x}}$$

$$\sin\theta=\dfrac{\sqrt{1-\cos x}-\cos x}{\sqrt{1+\cos x}}$$

$$\sin\theta=\dfrac{\left(\sqrt{1-\cos x}-\cos x\right)\sqrt{1+\cos x}}{1+\cos x}$$

$$\sin\theta=\dfrac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}-\cos x\cdot\sqrt{1+\cos x}}{1+\cos x}$$

$$\sin\theta=\dfrac{\sin x-\cos x\cdot\sqrt{1+\cos x}}{1+\cos x}$$

$$\sin\theta=\dfrac{\sin x-\sqrt{2}\cos x\cdot\cos \left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)}{1+\cos x}$$

But actual answer is $\tan^2\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)$. What am I missing here?

Comment: I believe it should be $$\cot^{-1}$$

Comment: I concur with lab bhattacharjee. Comparing the graph of $\sin{\theta}$ where $\theta$ is as given to the graph of $\tan^{2}{\frac{x}{2}}$ reveals that the supplied answer doesn't match the question

Answer (score 1):

Asssuming $\cot^{-1}$ in place of $\cos^{-1}$

$$\theta=\dfrac\pi2-2\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\cos x}=\dfrac\pi2-\tan^{-1}\dfrac{2\sqrt{\cos x}}{1-\cos x}$$

$$\cot\theta=\dfrac{2\sqrt{\cos x}}{1-\cos x}\ge0$$

$$\dfrac{\cos\theta}{2\sqrt{\cos x}}=\dfrac{\sin\theta}{1-\cos x}=\sqrt{\dfrac1{(2\sqrt{\cos x})^2+(1-\cos x)^2}}=\dfrac1{1+\cos x}$$

Comment: no its $\cos x$, only

Comment: @user3290550, Observe that the value of $$\sin\theta$ $nicely matches with the expected one

Answer (score 0):

We must have $\cos(x)\geq0$, so we require $x\in[-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n,\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n]$

Recall the identity

$$\arctan(u)+\text{arccot}(u)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

So we get

$$\sin(\theta)=\sin(\text{arccot}\sqrt{\cos(x)}-\arctan\sqrt{\cos(x)})=\sin(\pi/2-2\arctan\sqrt{\cos(x)})\\
=\cos(2\underbrace{\arctan\sqrt{\cos(x)}}_v)$$

From $\arctan(u)=\arcsin\Big(\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}\Big)$,

$$v=\arctan\sqrt{\cos(x)}=\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{\cos(x)}}{\sqrt{1+\cos(x)}}\right)=\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}}\right)$$

and so

$$\sin(\theta)=\cos(2v)=1-2\sin^2(v)=1-2\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\right)\\
=\frac{1-\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\cdot\frac{1-\cos(x)}{1-\cos(x)}=\frac{(1-\cos(x))^2}{\sin^2(x)}=\tan^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$

as desired.